# Как правильно реализовать глобальную функцию (класс)?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Мне надо создать глобальную статическую функцию (класс), которая будет в себе содержать некоторые поля и функции для работы с этими полями. Она должна быть в некотором `namespace` например, `App.global` и с названием, например, `MyGlobalFunction`. К ней будет за данными обращаться все приложение, так что надо, чтобы ничто не создавало экземпляров этого класса. Значит, к ней должно обращаться примерно так:

```
App.global.MyGlobalFunction.addMyData(myData);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как красиво ее реализовать.

Comment: Неужто никто никогда такого не делал?!!
Расскажите хоть кто-нибудь о СВОЕЙ практике.
Вдруг вариант окажется очень красивый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте синглтон:

```
App.global.MyGloabal = (function(){
    // private
    var __instance;
    var somePrivateVar;
    var simePrivateFunc = function(){};

    function constructor(/*constructor params*/) {
        return {/*return public object*/
              publicMethod1:function(){},
              publicMethod2:function(){},
              myField: 'somePuvlicValue'
        }
    }
    // public
    return {
         getInstance: function(){
              if(!__instance) {__instance = constructor()}
              return __instance;
         }
    }
})();
```

Используется так:

```
  App.global.MyGlobal.getInstance().publicMethod1();
  App.global.MyGlobal.getInstance().publicMethod2();
  var field = App.global.MyGlobal.getInstance().myField;
```

---

Естественно конструктор должен возвращать готовый для работы объект с необходимыми полями и методами, все что вне этого возвращаемого обьекта (за исключением getInstance) приватные данные, естественно конструктору тоже можно передавать параметры. Преймущества такого подхода очевидны - настоящая инкапсуляция, экономия памяти, структурирование. Многие спецы и авторитетные источники советуют использовать этот шаблон настолько часто насколько это возможно (во всяком случае такой подход хоть немного позволяет уберечь новичков от жесткого спагетти кода), причиной тому является то, что, практически в любом JS коде количество необходимых объектов какой-то сущности === 1. Ну а если вам нужно >1 - тогда просто используйте какой-либо другой шаблон

---

И реализовывайте себе сколько угодно методов и полей с полной уверенностью в том, что экземпляр публичного объекта всегда 1.

Comment: Спасибо за такой хороший и вразумительный ответ!

Comment: Спасибо за  интересный вопрос =) (что здесь увы редкость)

Comment: ИМХО - сложновато... Проще - сразу из замыкания возвращать рабочий объект ( а не получать его через getInstance() )

Comment: Во первых ничего не мешает в коде написать:

      var obj = namespace.ololo.MyClass.getInstance();

и работать с ним как с отдельным объектом.

Суть в том что этот вариант подходит для любой задачи, при возвращении объекта из замыкания вы инициализируете обьект во время загрузки, сдесь же инициализация происходит во время вызова getInstance и может зависеть от передаваемых параметоров.
Эту разницу надо понимать. 

Более того вы можете написать какую угодно логику обработки этих параметров (что еще 1 + для маневров)

Comment: Да и singletone как бы стандартный паттерн, что сложного то? Или вы его никогда не использовали? Насколько я понимаю для любого программиста структура `ClassName.getInstance().someMethod` не должна быть чем-либо страшным...

Comment: "getInstance и может зависеть" - это тогда не Singleton ))

Comment: @timka_s - singletone + lazy initialization, не хотел просто напрягать незнающих страшными буквами, но раз вы настаиваете...
****
Правило синглтона в том что объект может быть инициализирован только 1 раз, если это правило исполняется - это singletone. 
****
Надо понимать что шаблоны проектирования имеют разные группы и они так или иначе могут совмещаться...

ps:posted special 4 @timka_s

Comment: @timka_s, вы можете тоже оставить свой вариант. Уверен, он во многих ситуациях тоже сможет быть полезен.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть какая-то инициализация, либо, вдруг, вам нужны приватные переменные:

```
App.global.MyGlobal = (function(init_val){
  var obj = {
        prop1: 'val1',
        prop2: init_val
      },
      // v - сокращение от var, т.е. локальный объект
      v = {
        private_prop1: 'val1'
      };

  obj.fn1 = function (){
    return obj.prop1 + obj.prop2 + v.private_prop1;
  };

  obj.fn2 = function (){};

  return obj;
})('my_init_val');
```

Обычно-же, достаточно просто:

```
App.global.MyGlobal = {
  prop1: 'val1',
  prop2: 'val2',
  fn1: function (){
    return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
  },
  fn2: function (){}
}
```

Работать так:

```
App.global.MyGlobal.fn1();
```

Comment: А зачем   
>>return obj;
в вашем первом примере?

Comment: )) Что-бы вернуть объект, созданный внутри функции, и поместить его в App.global.MyGlobal

Comment: А как вам вариант, когда   
>> App.global.MyGlobal = new function() {
>>  var obj = 'bla-bla';
>>  this.getObj = function() {return obj + 'asdhfhsdga';}
>>}

Comment: Можно и так... Только `funtion(){}` надо в круглые скобки взять

P.S: имена переменных/методов лучше поменять)))